# Using a MIN MAX query over a DISTINCT one in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, distinct, min

With my new job, I am needing to use **SQL** more and more. As I need to remove **duplicate columns** I thought that using a `DISTINCT` statement would be best. However, I was indicated that a `MIN MAX` statement might be more suited. As I am still fairly new to SQL I was wondering if I could get some advice on when to use one over the other. All help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

First, the construct is `select distinct`, not just `distinct`.  That is an important distinction, and one that people learning SQL often confuse.

Second, `select distinct` and `min()`/`max()` do different things.  The latter are aggregation functions and should be used with `group by`.

In my opinion, `select distinct` is an unnecessary part of the SQL language.  Almost everything it does can be handled by `group by`.  It is much better for you to learn to use `group by` correctly.  (And, as a side note, `select distinct` is almost never useful with `group by`.)

Comment: You're the expert here, but I disagree with select distinct not being useful. I make use of it frequently. Sometimes it makes more logical sense to the programmers when reading the code than using group by. Group by can do everything select distinct can, but a wrench can occasionally make a pretty decent hammer too.

Comment: I also disagree about distinct not being useful. To me it is much clearer to say **select distinct dummy from dual** than it is to say **select dummy from dual group by dummy**. Clarity is always important.

Comment: @SandPiper . . . I didn't say "not useful", I said "unnecessary".  It is pretty trivially replaced with a `group by`, in all cases except `select distinct *`.

Answer (score 0):

Max and Min each return a single result (one record with the Max or Min value) whereas DISTINCT returns **all** unique values (avoiding duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
column_name_one, MAX(column_name_two)
FROM
table_name
GROUP BY column_name_one  
ORDER BY `table_name`.`column_name_one` ASC
```

I've tried this query in practice and it has returned all distinct values without explicitly writing distinct. Also it returns result in Ascending order so can be useful while exporting.

> **NOTE:** MIN() can be used instead of MAX () to get minimum values as well.